# How to divide a count() number by a number in Mongodb/Python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to divide a number that I got from the database collection which is the count() below by the numeric value 5929. I tried the below but syntax error is occurred. Can anyone enlighten me on how I can do this?

```
db.enron.find( $divide:[({'text': {"$regex":"Kenneth Lay"}}).count() , 5929])
```

Comment: `$divide` is an aggregation operator, so you can use it in `find`, but why aren't you just dividing the count by 5929 in your code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would you do that? Do you think you can provide an example?

Comment: As in: `db.enron.find({'text': {"$regex":"Kenneth Lay"}}).count() / 5929`